# How to set ListView Column Header Property IsHitTestVisible to False programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am adding columns to my ListView programmaticaly with this line of code:

```
gridView.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = myWorksheet.Cells(1, myVar).Value, .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding(myWorksheet.Cells(1, myVar).Value)})
```

What I want to do is set the HitTest to False so the user cannot resize the columns that were added, I tried doing this in my XAML but it did not work:

```
<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
```

This probably requires a solution in VB.Net because the XAML code does not apply to columns created programmaticaly?

---

Added C# tag because I found out it can be converted to VB.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML style is applied to all columns added in XAML and from code behind. If you want to set `IsHitTestVisible` not for all, but only for some column's header, then it will be tricky.

I don't know elegant solution for it. So far I know there is no way to get easy `GridViewColumnHeader` object, which will be styled.

My offer would be to inject a control instead of setting header text, e.g. `TextBlock`, which will iterate through parents and set `GridViewColumnHeader.IsHitTestVisible` to false.

```
public class TextBlockNoHit<ParentHitTestVisibleType> : TextBlock where ParentHitTestVisibleType: UIElement 
{
    public bool lsParentHitTestVisible { get; set; }
    public TextBlockNoHit()
    {
        Loaded += TextBlockNoHit_Loaded;
    }

    private void TextBlockNoHit_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= TextBlockNoHit_Loaded;
                
        DependencyObject dpo = this;
        while(dpo!=null)
        {
            dpo = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dpo);
            if(dpo is ParentHitTestVisibleType gvch)
            {
                gvch.IsHitTestVisible = lsParentHitTestVisible;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using then:

```
var col = new GridViewColumn() { Header = new TextBlockNoHit<GridViewColumnHeader>() { Text = "myWorksheet.Cells...", IsHitTestVisible = false, lsParentHitTestVisible = false}, DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("myWorksheet.Cells...") };
```

Comment: Sorry for C# instead of VB, I hope you will get a conversion.

Comment: IDK, I tried several XAML solutions in my ListView and none of them stopped me from resizing the columns, believe me I tried, then I looked into how to do it programatically because I thought there's no way for it to work that way.

I'll try out your solution :), thank you!